# install python 2.x and 3.x on the same windows computer

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, exe

I currently have python 3.3 installed on my windows 7 computer. i have the .exe set as an alias such that i can compile and run programs through cmd.

i'd like to install python 2.7 so that I can later turn my program into a .exe . How can I install python 2.7 on my computer, and then run it so that it compiles with 2.7 and not 3.3?

Comment: Your question is a bit puzzling.  Using Python 2.7 versus 3.3 has nothing to do with "turning your program into a .exe".  Also, the two versions of Python are not totally compatible, so code that runs on 3.3 may not run on 2.7.  Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: what i've already done when i installed python 3.3, is i modified the environment variable (see youtube.com/watch?v=L5t5U0XnSew#t=264) can i do this for python 2.7, and say, have a different keyword to launch? otherwise, how can i run a program in 2.7 with 3.3 in my path?

Comment: When installing 2.7 on a system that already has 3.3, remember to disable updating file associations. You want to keep the .py extension associated with py.exe.

Comment: Python 3.3 also installs something called the [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pylauncher) which is invoked via a `py.exe`. If you have another version of Python also installed, you can control which one is used by using command line arguments or via a shebang comment at the start of your scripts, like `#!/usr/bin/env python` as is common in linux os systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) for Python 3.3 it also installs Python 2.7 but with a different name py.exe instead of the default python.exe.

Comment: The 3.3 installer doesn't install 2.7. It installs the new py launcher, which defaults to running 2.7 if you already have that version installed. use `py -X.Y` to run version X.Y.